# remove string after the second underscore and last underscore in this file name:MM_980765465Z_2022_03_Shared. I need this to be MM_980765465Z_Shared

Tags: powershell

I am trying to bulk rename files using powershell and would need help on the below: remove string after the second underscore and last underscore in this file name:MM_980765465Z_2022_03_Shared. I need this to be MM_980765465Z_Shared

Comment: `$_.name.split('_')[0,1,-1] -join '_'` would do it in a loop

Answer (score 2):

If the string always follow the same naming convention this could work:

```
$string = 'MM_980765465Z_2022_03_Shared'
-join ($string -split '(?=_)')[0, 1, -1]
```